# Displaying login page properly on desktop screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I recently created my first application using dart and flutter. There is one login page that is created using these technologies. The page is properly displayed for mobile devices screens size. But, when it is displayed on the desktop screens, it is not properly displayed. It is stretched to the full screen width. I used dart and flutter. Please help me and guide me how can I make the login screen displayed properly on desktop screens. Please refer the image shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the page (body) in a `Container` with `constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth:)`.